# How to create a communication setup between a Mysql and a MS SQL Server instance?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-connection

I have two separate appliations running on the separate infrastructure. app-a is using MYSQL as it's database server and, app-b is using MS SQL Server as database server. I have got requirement to constantly read some tables in the MS SQL server and populate some table in MYSQL server.

I got clue about setup a communication environment for my MYSQL database server and a external MS SQL server(Using DBlink).

Please provide your expert opinions for this setup? Is this possible to setup such a environment? If Yes; How does it work? And what is the process to set it up?

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: You could use a Linked Server instance on the SQL Server instance to push data to the MySQL database.  Both perform the same action, I don't have a preference either way.

Comment: Unable to make any idea from it! :( please put some more insight on the topic.

Comment: @OMG, Thanks, So, It was that all you were pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221), describe the process for doing something like this. But this solution only works form MS SQL server perspective. As per my findings there is no support for such a functionality in the MySql part.